# Calculating the product of all the odd numbers

Tags: matlab, for-loop

So I am trying to create a script that calculates the product of all the odd numbers from 1 to 1000 (using MATLAB).  The program runs but the product is not correct:
%Program is meant to calculate the product of all the odd numbers from 1 to 1000

```
% declare variable ‘product’ as zero

product = 0.;

% initialize counter, ‘n’, to 1000

n = 1000;

for i = 1:2:n

product = product + i;

end

fprintf('The product of all the odd numbers from 1 to %d is %d\n', n, product)
```

So I'm not really sure how to go about this and am looking for some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Are your really trying to calculate the product by summing?: `product = product + i;`. You might also look at the `prod` function and avoid the `for` loop entirely.

Comment: `product = product + i;` looks like a very odd way of computing a product.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Currently, your script is set to **add** all of the odd numbers from 1 to 1000.
To perform the product, you just need to change the starting value of `product` to 1 and multiply within the loop:

```
product = 1;
for i = 1:2:1000
  product = product * i;
end
```

However, it is faster to create a vector and have the built-in `prod` function perform the multiplication:

```
product = prod(1:2:1000);
```

### Problem

MATLAB does not by default have enough memory in the default 64-bit numbers to compute the exact value of this product.
The number is too large since this is essentially a factorial.

You'll find that MATLAB returns `Inf` for the 500 numbers you're multiplying, and it is only finite for up to 150 elements.
In fact, using floating point arithmetic, the number is [only accurate up to 15 digits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html?refresh=true) for the first 17 digits using floats (integers saturate at that level as well).

Using Mathematica (which can perform arbitrary digit arithmetic out-of-the-box since I'm feeling lazy), I can see that the answer needs at least 1300 digits of precision, which we can have MATLAB do through the Symbolic Toolbox's [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) function:

```
digits(1300);
p    = vpa(1);
pint = vpa(1);
for k = 2:N
    pint = pint*p(k);
end
disp(pint);

>> StackOverflow
100748329763750854004038917392303538250323418583550415705013777513334847930864905026212149922688916514224446856302103818809813965739969905602683824057028542369814437703275217182106137628427025253936696857063927677887236450311036887007989218384076420973974651860279864376153012567675767840733574225799002463604490891982796305162134708837541147007332276627034016790073315219533088052639255340728943149219519187498959529434982654113006616219355830114439411562650611374970334868978510289340267833632215930432706056111069583472778227977585526504938921664232801595705593340414168289146933191250605578218896799783237156997993612173843567447982392426109444012350386990916069363415575527636429080027392875413821124412782341957015410685185402984322002697631153866494712956244870206835064084512590679022924697003630949759950902438767963278695296882620493296103779237046934780464541286585179975172680371269700518965123152181467825566303777704391998857792627009043170482928030252033752456172692668989206857862233381387134495504231267039972111966329704875185659372569246229419619030694680808504265784672316785572965414328005856656944666840982779185954031239345256896720409853053597049715408663604581472840976596002762935980048845023622727663267632821809277089697420848324327380396425724029541015625.0
```

Comment: Thanks Troy! Question, what is the p variable used for in the vpa function?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be a 1.